# dynamic web page automatic snapshot

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, jquery

I have a dynamic web site (php/mySQL/Ajax on a Linux server), I need to take automatically a photo (snapshot) of each web page periodically (If I can find the way to do the snapshot... I can use cron) and save this image to the database (I also know how to do this...my only problem is the photo!).

I can't do it manually, so I need an script which take the snapshop for me, without displaying the web page, i.e directly from the .php files.

How is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd question the real need for a screenshot, can't you just save the rendered html, that is trival in linux!

Answer (score 3):

http://browsershots.org/ may work for you, they have an api

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GD functions [`imagegrabscreen()`](http://www.php.net/imagegrabscreen) or [`imagegrabwindow()`](http://www.php.net/imagegrabwindow) to take a screenshot.

Note that they're only available on Windows at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](http://www.codediesel.com/php/taking-screenshots-of-websites-in-php/) might answer your question, I have seen it done with php and flash but wasn't privy to the inner workings, if the link doesnt help then you could research that route.

Comment: I know this might be an out of scope suggestion but you could try to use [link]phantom.js.org which would solve your problem nicely, but may require a bit of node.js (which can run on lamp stacks)