# Cleanest, most cross-browser compatible way to display multiple size-scaled web pages within a single page

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe, scaling

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET that deals with pages that display a bunch of gauge etc, with changing values.

For part of the navigation I need to be able to display small previews of a bunch of these pages on a single page.

It may be a lot to ask, but the previews must fit into the same size 'frame' regardless of their original size, have equal scaling (1:1, blank space is acceptable), and be as cross-browser capable as possible (at least work on IE, FF, Opera, Safari & Safari for iPhone/Pad/Pod).

I've been trying to use html iframes to achieve this but I'm finding the results to be highly unpredictable across different web browsers, and some conflicts with it's style attributes against its other parameters.

Implementation of this can be within the navigation page or the control pages or both.

Answer (score 0):

The only cross-browser solution for this is to create a snapshot of the page on server side, and display it as an image.

Related questions:

- [dynamic web page automatic snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671631/dynamic-web-page-automatic-snapshot)
- [Convert URL to screenshot (script).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811674/convert-url-to-screenshot-script)

Comment: Darn. You beat me to it by 57 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking screenshots and using browser detection to display only the correct images. There's probably a better way to do it, but this should at least get you started. You can use adobe browser labs if you need a screenshot for a browser you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Do the previews have to be "live", or can they be static? And are all pages available on the internet (in which case you might be able to use an online screenshot service) or are they internal pages?

Comment: (At least to a small degree, possibly a single preview of the initial page values)